# glCheckFramebufferStatus returns 36062

Tags: opengl, constants, glew

**Problem:** glCheckFramebufferStatus returns value(36062) that doesn't match any documented Constant.

I'm trying to create a Framebuffer Object and then check its status, however glCheckFramebufferStatus returns a value that doesn't match any constant.
Am I doing something wrong? All other commands worked so far.

*Code (BlitzMax):*

```
glGenFramebuffers(1, Varptr gl_Framebuffer)
glGenTextures(1, Varptr gl_FramebufferTex)
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, gl_FramebufferTex)
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, vRW, vRH, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0)
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, gl_Framebuffer)
glFramebufferTextureARB(GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, gl_FramebufferTex, 0)
glFramebufferTextureARB(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, gl_FramebufferTex, 0)

Local fbo0Status:Int = glCheckFramebufferStatus(gl_Framebuffer)
Select fbo0Status
    Case GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_ATTACHMENT
        Print "[FBO0] GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_ATTACHMENT"
    ...
    Default
        Print "[FBO0] GL_I_DONT_KNOW_THIS_FREAKING_VALUE (" + fbo0Status + ")"
EndSelect
```

Comment: What GPU/driver are you using?

Comment: AMD ATI CCC 13.1 in combination with an ATI Radeon 5770.

Comment: Don't use `glFramebufferTextureARB`. Use `glFramebufferTexture` instead.

Comment: There's glFramebufferTexture2D, if you mean that one. glFramebufferTexture doesn't exist in my copy of Pub.Glew.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I ran into this problem also while following some erroneous FBO demo code. After half an hour of debugging, I figured out the problem.

The issue here is the code

```
Local fbo0Status:Int = glCheckFramebufferStatus(gl_Framebuffer)
```

According to OpenGL documentation here:

http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man3/xhtml/glCheckFramebufferStatus.xml

You should not be passing in the framebuffer id. Instead you should be passing in GL_FRAMEBUFFER.

The specifications state that upon passing an invalid value to glCheckFramebufferStatus(), it should generate GL_INVALID_ENUM. However this seems to be a driver bug as it generates 36062 instead.

Comment: We must have been following the same erroneous FBO demo code then. I was reading a tutorial on how to get the depth buffer accessible to the shader, and it suggested framebuffer objects.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I can say this: 0x8CDE (36062 in hex) not only doesn't match any expected return value from `glCheckFramebufferStatus`, it doesn't match *any enum in OpenGL*.

So this is clearly a driver bug.

That being said, your code is redundant. You don't need to attach the same texture to the same framebuffer on the same attachment point *twice*. Binding to `GL_FRAMEBUFFER` binds the same FBO to the `READ` and `DRAW` framebuffers simultaneously. So your two `glFramebufferTexture` calls are just redundant.

That shouldn't cause a problem though.

Comment: I changed the attaching code to only once, and it didn't change the outcome, like you said. I've reported this to AMD/ATI, I hope that this is fixed in their next driver release.

Comment: @Xaymar: I can guarantee that it *won't* be fixed in their next driver release. It generally takes ~3+ months for a fix to filter through their monthly release patches.